# Why azure sql's sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups not updating?

Tags: azure-sql-database, dmv

I have an azure sql db and run sp_BlitzIndex from brentozar on it to identify some missing indexes. This sp actually uses sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups, basically use these query:

```
select xxx FROM    sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups ig
JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details id ON ig.index_handle = id.index_handle
JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats gs ON ig.index_group_handle = gs.group_handle
```

However, I realised that after I created these missing indexes, above query will still show the same indexes as missing and it has been like that for around 12 hours now.

The doc says:

> Information returned by sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups is updated when
>   a query is optimized by the query optimizer

So it should be real time info, so why this information seems not updating?

Comment: Is [automatic tuning option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automatic-tuning) on?

Comment: no. we don't really want blindly apply indexes. As in some cases, it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Have you found on the cache query plans with missing indexes that you cannot see on the result of your query? If you do not see new missing indexes on your query plans then those DMVs should show the same results.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES
   (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')

SELECT query_plan,
       n.value('(@StatementText)[1]', 'VARCHAR(4000)') AS sql_text,
       n.value('(//MissingIndexGroup/@Impact)[1]', 'FLOAT') AS impact,
       DB_ID(REPLACE(REPLACE(n.value('(//MissingIndex/@Database)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)'),'[',''),']','')) AS database_id,
       OBJECT_ID(n.value('(//MissingIndex/@Database)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') + '.' +
           n.value('(//MissingIndex/@Schema)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') + '.' +
           n.value('(//MissingIndex/@Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)')) AS OBJECT_ID,
       n.value('(//MissingIndex/@Database)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') + '.' +
           n.value('(//MissingIndex/@Schema)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') + '.' +
           n.value('(//MissingIndex/@Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)')
       AS statement,
       (   SELECT DISTINCT c.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') + ', '
           FROM n.nodes('//ColumnGroup') AS t(cg)
           CROSS APPLY cg.nodes('Column') AS r(c)
           WHERE cg.value('(@Usage)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') = 'EQUALITY'
           FOR  XML PATH('')
       ) AS equality_columns,
        (  SELECT DISTINCT c.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') + ', '
           FROM n.nodes('//ColumnGroup') AS t(cg)
           CROSS APPLY cg.nodes('Column') AS r(c)
           WHERE cg.value('(@Usage)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') = 'INEQUALITY'
           FOR  XML PATH('')
       ) AS inequality_columns,
       (   SELECT DISTINCT c.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') + ', '
           FROM n.nodes('//ColumnGroup') AS t(cg)
           CROSS APPLY cg.nodes('Column') AS r(c)
           WHERE cg.value('(@Usage)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') = 'INCLUDE'
           FOR  XML PATH('')
       ) AS include_columns
INTO #MissingIndexInfo
FROM
(
   SELECT query_plan
   FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT plan_handle
           FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats WITH(NOLOCK)
         ) AS qs
       OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) tp
   WHERE tp.query_plan.exist('//MissingIndex')=1
) AS tab (query_plan)
CROSS APPLY query_plan.nodes('//StmtSimple') AS q(n)
WHERE n.exist('QueryPlan/MissingIndexes') = 1;

-- Trim trailing comma from lists
UPDATE #MissingIndexInfo
SET equality_columns = LEFT(equality_columns,LEN(equality_columns)-1),
   inequality_columns = LEFT(inequality_columns,LEN(inequality_columns)-1),
   include_columns = LEFT(include_columns,LEN(include_columns)-1);

SELECT *
FROM #MissingIndexInfo;

DROP TABLE #MissingIndexInfo;
```